# Unresolved Reference "content" in JSONResponse

Tags: python, unit-testing, jsonresponse

So, I've been trying to write unit tests for a function that returns a `JSONResponse` that contains a `status_code` and `content`. The function looks like this:

```
def exception_handler(request):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": NotFoundException} if is_development() else {}),
    )
```

I'm testing for two cases: `is_development()` returns `True` or `False`. When I'm calling the function to test it like this: `response = exception_handler(request)` I can access `response.status_code` but not `response.content`. Why is that? I wanna access the content in order to check if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really reproduce your problem. Here is the code which works in my case.

```py
# ---- Some setup, to make your example work ----
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

class status:
    HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND = 404

class JSONResponse:

    def __init__(self,  status_code, content):
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.content = content


# ----- Here your code -----
def exception_handler(request):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": None} if is_development() else {}),
    )


def is_development():
    """True and False work"""
    return False


print(vars(exception_handler(None)))
```

Output:

```
{'status_code': 404, 'content': {}}
```

Could you provide more information?